# filling a Dictionary<> with an IEnumerable<> source

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, ienumerable

I have a VS2008 C# .NET 3.5 application where I would like to create a hashtable of objects given an IEnumerable list of those objects.

Basically, it looks like this:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    where T: IMyData, new()
{
    private IDictionary<int, string> collection_ = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    // ...

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        collection_.Add(item.ID, item.Text);
    }

    public static MyCollection<T> Create(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        MyCollection<T> c = new MyCollection<T>();
        foreach(T item in source)
        {
            c.Add(item);
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

This works, but I wonder if there isn't a better way of copying from one IEnumerable source to another. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: Your `Create` method seems nonsensical; it creates an empty `MyCollection<T>` named `c`, does stuff to the elements of its parameter `source`, then returns the still-empty `c`. And I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt assuming `IMyData` has an `Add` method.

Comment: @Domenic - You're right. I copied that badly. I've corrected it. Your answer was what I was looking for, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
return source.ToDictionary(item => item.ID, item => item.Text);
```